# reactjs/laravel 'npm run development' fails with syntax error 'Unexpected Token'

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I updated babel to the latest version and still get the error pointing to the "=" operator

```
  35 | export const AssignmentsContainer = connectedContainer(
  36 |     class extends Component {
> 37 |         buildAssignments = () => {
     |                          ^
```

debug.log doesn't really offer any obvious hints

The package.json at this point looks like this:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.12",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
}
```

}

Also tried sifting through this, but keep coming up empty: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1402

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class properties are still not supported. So, you need to use `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` which will help to transform class properties.

You need to install the babel plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

And, in your `.babelrc` file, you need to make an entry:

```
"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
```

This will solve your issue.

In the link you shared, it was mentioned to use `"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"`, but that's for older version of Babel. Since [Babel v7 the name has been changed](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#switch-to-proposal-for-tc39-proposals-blog-2017-12-27-nearing-the-70-releasehtml-renames-proposal) to `"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"`

**For Babel versions previous to 7:**

Install the babel-plugin-transform-class-properties plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

Then, make an entry in .babelrc:

```
"plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
```

Comment: I don't see a '.babelrd' file in the root of the project

Comment: In that case I guess you need to create a .babelrc in root folder.

Comment: ... hm, i did that and now i'm getting: Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error
to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.

Comment: Ok..But you said latest Babel. Then you need to follow the link you shared. I am updating the answer.